# Place Relative Min Value Of A Column Into Single Column Data Frame R

Tags: r, min

I am working with a data frame in R and I would like to find the min value for each date and then place that value in a single column in the data frame. The catch is that the min value for each date should appear only in the rows of that date. Please look at the below and this will be clearer.

```
        Date    Last
1 2015-06-21 2106.25
2 2015-06-21 2105.25
3 2015-06-21 2105.75
4 2015-06-22 2106.75
5 2015-06-22 2107.00
6 2015-06-22 2106.75
7 2015-06-23 2117.25
8 2015-06-23 2117.25
9 2015-06-23 2117.00
```

Desired output:

```
        Date    Last     Min
1 2015-06-21 2106.25 2105.25
2 2015-06-21 2105.25 2105.25  
3 2015-06-21 2105.75 2105.25
4 2015-06-22 2106.75 2106.75 
5 2015-06-22 2107.00 2106.75
6 2015-06-22 2106.75 2106.75
7 2015-06-23 2117.25 2117.00
8 2015-06-23 2117.25 2117.00
9 2015-06-23 2117.00 2117.00
```

To extract the min from each date, I am using:

```
MinVal <- sapply(split(data, data$Date), function(x) min(x$Last))
```

The output is fine:

```
2015-06-21 2015-06-22 2015-06-23 
   2105.25    2106.75    2117.00
```

Now, how do I get this back into the dataframe in a single column called Min? Using this sapply creates a matrix which I don't want:

```
data$Min <- sapply(names(MinVal), function(i) ifelse(data$Date == i, MinVal[i], NA))
```

This command will create the initial data frame:

```
data <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(16607, 16607, 16607, 16608, 
16608, 16608, 16609, 16609, 16609), class = "Date"), Last = c(2106.25, 
2105.25, 2105.75, 2106.75, 2107, 2106.75, 2117.25, 2117.25, 2117
)), .Names = c("Date", "Last"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
9L))
```

Thank you!

Comment: Try just `data$Min <- with(data, ave(Last, Date, FUN = min))`

Comment: Thank you very much David. One thing with R, in order to use a function, you need to know it exists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider using the package `data.table` for operations such as this. Here is an example:

```
library(data.table)

datadt <- data.table(data)

datadt[,Min:=min(Last),by=Date]

datadt
```

Which results in your desired result:

```
         Date    Last     Min
1: 2015-06-21 2106.25 2105.25
2: 2015-06-21 2105.25 2105.25
3: 2015-06-21 2105.75 2105.25
4: 2015-06-22 2106.75 2106.75
5: 2015-06-22 2107.00 2106.75
6: 2015-06-22 2106.75 2106.75
7: 2015-06-23 2117.25 2117.00
8: 2015-06-23 2117.25 2117.00
9: 2015-06-23 2117.00 2117.00
```

The `:=` operator in `data.table` allows you to create columns on an existing data.table. The by argument can do this `by` a unique group.

Answer (score 2):

One way with `dplyr`:

```
data %>%
  group_by(Date) %>%      #group
  mutate(Min = min(Last)) #add min Last per group
```

Output:

```
Source: local data frame [9 x 3]
Groups: Date

        Date    Last     Min
1 2015-06-21 2106.25 2105.25
2 2015-06-21 2105.25 2105.25
3 2015-06-21 2105.75 2105.25
4 2015-06-22 2106.75 2106.75
5 2015-06-22 2107.00 2106.75
6 2015-06-22 2106.75 2106.75
7 2015-06-23 2117.25 2117.00
8 2015-06-23 2117.25 2117.00
9 2015-06-23 2117.00 2117.00
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution:

```
cbind(data[order(data$Date),],Min=min(data$Last))
```

Output:

```
        Date    Last     Min
1 2015-06-21 2106.25 2105.25
2 2015-06-21 2105.25 2105.25
3 2015-06-21 2105.75 2105.25
4 2015-06-22 2106.75 2105.25
5 2015-06-22 2107.00 2105.25
6 2015-06-22 2106.75 2105.25
7 2015-06-23 2117.25 2105.25
8 2015-06-23 2117.25 2105.25
9 2015-06-23 2117.00 2105.25
```